# Duplicating a canvas with its contents at run-time in WP7 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Can I make something like a 'mold' of a canvas with its contents, such that I can then make as many copies as I want at run-time?

If anybody can tell me the way or even an alternative to do that please.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap(v=VS.95).aspx and http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com

There was an article in MSDN Magazine in the last year that showed a kaleidoscope app that copied and inverted frames of video from the camera. I can't find the link to it right now, but that should be close to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found that creating a user control, putting all contents in, then using that control whenever I want, solves the problem.

[WP7 Tutorial Custom ListBox Item with CheckBox and Circle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wATgStBdsxI)

Thanks.